# Moving objects between database tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using SELECT to retrieve certain items from MySQL. While the statement is fetching, I want to take each returned row and move certain information from it into a different table.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT info FROM table");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($info);

$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO another_table (info) VALUES (?)");
$stmt2->bind_param('s', $info);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {

    //$info is different for each loop
    $stmt2->execute();

}
```

This does not work. Nothing happens after `$stmt2->bind_param()`. However, I am able to populate an array with `$info` in the while loop, and afterward use the *same exact* database code to insert the info from the array into the other table. However, the array could potentially become too large and cause memory issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you’d normally put `bind_param` in the loop. But you’re probably able to do it in one query:

```sql
INSERT INTO another_table(info) SELECT info FROM table;
```

Comment: Can you explain how that query works? What if I wanted to include variables from PHP so that they are included in the same row as `info` in the second table? How would I insert them into that query (where would I put the question mark)?

Comment: @JackHumphries: `INSERT INTO` can take values from another table using `SELECT`, and that’s what that does. If you wanted to put in the same value for every row, it would look like `INSERT INTO another_table(info, other_column) SELECT info, ? FROM table`, I think…